A question on proving an inequality involving a sequence of real numbers
Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $1=a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le \cdots \le a_n.$
Additionally, we have that $a_{i+1}-a_i \le \sqrt{a_i},$ for all $1 \le i <n.$
Then prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i} \le 2 \log_2 n.$$
My attempt:
Consider the LHS of the given inequality to be proved.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{a_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}.$$
Since we have that $1=a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le \cdots \le a_n,$ we get that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} \le 1$ for all $1 \le i <n.$ Hence, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i} \le  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} \le n-1.$$
I know that this is very loose bound on the given sum.
How can I possibly improve this? Please give any hints or suggestions. Thanks for all your inputs in advance.

seems like a strategy could be to prove this for the actual recurrence with equality sign and then argue that that is the "largest" possible such sequence of a given length.

@dezdichado i dont think if that is gonna work as if all are equal sum will just come out to be $0$ but even if a single term is different the sum will be a positive quantity which is greater than $0$

@YashShrivastava I said the recurrence has the equality sign, not the numbers.

$\def\le{\leqslant}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$Since for $1 \le k \le n - 1$,$$
2(\sqrt{a_{k + 1}} - \sqrt{a_k}) \le \frac{1}{ \sqrt{a_k} } (\sqrt{a_{k + 1}} + \sqrt{a_k}) \cdot (\sqrt{a_{k + 1}} - \sqrt{a_k}) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{a_k} } (a_{k + 1} - a_k) \le 1,
$$
then $1 \le a_k \leqslant \dfrac{1}{4} (k + 1)^2$ for $1 \le k \le n$ by induction. Note that$$
a_{k + 1} \le a_k + \sqrt{a_k} \le 2a_k \quad (1 \le k \le n - 1),
$$
and$$
x - 1 \le \frac{ \ln x }{ \ln 2 } = \log_2 x \quad (x \in [1, 2])
$$
since $\ln x$ is concave, thus\begin{gather*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{a_k} (a_{k + 1} - a_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \paren{ \frac{a_{k + 1}}{a_k} - 1 } \le \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \log_2 \frac{a_{k + 1}}{a_k}\\
= \log_2 a_n - \log_2 a_1 \le \log_2\paren{ \frac{1}{4} (n + 1)^2 } \le \log_2 n^2 = 2\log_2 n.
\end{gather*}
Remark: The solution is inspired by considering the differential version of the condition and the result, i.e.:

Let $f \in C^1([1, +\infty))$ be an increasing function such that $f(1) = 1$ and$$
f'(x) \le \sqrt{f(x)} \quad (x \in (1, +\infty)).
$$
Then$$
\int_1^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \,\mathrm{d} t \le 2 \ln\frac{x}{2} \quad (x \in [1, +\infty)).
$$

The above version can be solved by the method of variation of constants.

Thanks for your interest in my question @SAAD.
I have a doubt regarding your solution. In the solution, it is stated that $$x-1 \le \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}= \log_2 x \text{ for all } x \in [0,2].$$
However this is NOT true. Take $x=0.5 = \frac{1}{2}.$ We have that $x-1=-0.5$ and $\log_2 (0.5) = -1.$
I am trying to check whether this affects the solution that you have provided. Still, I wanted to let know my thoughts.

And also, you have mentioned regarding the differential version of the condition. I could not understand it. Can you please elaborate. Thanks in advance.

@MathRookie2204 The range for the mentioned inequality should be $[1,2]$ instead, and I've added the analog version.

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ how do you get $a_{k+1} = a_k+\frac1{\sqrt{a_k}}$?

Maybe you meant $a_{k+1} \le a_k +\sqrt{a_k} \le 2a_k$?

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ $a_{k+1} \color{red}{\le} ...$
